# How to demand multiple agent machines in Azure devops pipeline pool?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm looking if I can specify a list of agents in Agent pool demands? In UI azure pipeline has only two options equals and exists. So, I tried adding two demands but pipeline takes only first demand

[image: Pipeline UI]

The same in yaml is as follows,

```
pool:
  name: AWS Pool
  demands:
  - Agent.Name -equals simLin02
  - Agent.Name -equals ubuAgent01
```

I would like to know if there is any logical way of specifying the list of agent machines in yaml like following or any other alternatives where I can pass a list of agent names(specific agent names because not all agents in the pool have desired capability) for the pipeline to choose from.

```
pool:
  name: AWS Pool
  demands:
  - Agent.Name -in (simLin02, ubuAgent01)
```

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I mean I know of adding the capability but the problem is I don't have access to creating capabilities, I only know of machines that I need to choose from. Anyway, thank you for confirming that I cant send a list of machines to choose from that helps me in moving forward.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry but as I know Azure Devops doesn't support specifying the list of agent machines using the logical way above. Instead we can define [user-defined capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities) if we want to pass a list of agents for the pipeline to choose from. See:

[image]

For example: If we define one custom capability called `RunTest` for agents `simLin02` and `ubuAgent01`, then we can easily use something like this to choose the list which contains these two agents:

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands: RunTest
```

Since only agents `simLin02` and `ubuAgent01` contain the `RunTest` capability, it will pick one of them to run the pipeline. It actually has same effect like `- Agent.Name -in (simLin02, ubuAgent01)` whose syntax is not supported.