# Select agent from a pool in accordance to its current state

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to select a particular agent from a pool if it is idle else if it's in the active state then I would like to select the next agent with a particular name, and if this agent is also not idle I would like to select the next agent which matches a particular name.

Something of this format.

> ```
> pool:                          
> name: Default
> demands:
> -Agent.Name -equals MACHINE1 -or MACHINE2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your concerns but it's not supported to select the agent in sequence.

The selection of an agent from the pool for a job is handled by Azure DevOps itself and it’s not exposed for users to control programmatically.

What we can achieve currently is picking the `idle` agent from the pool, but cannot guarantee which one is picked up firstly. Please refer the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63629379/14996050) about adding same custom capabilities and use it for demands value.

If you would like the feature, it's recommended to raise a feature request in link [here](https://aka.ms/AzDevOpsIdeas).

Comment: So, we cannot give a list of agents to connect to from a pool. We can only specify name of one agent.

Comment: Yes. To give a list of agents, the workaround is shared in the mentioned [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63629379/14996050) above, what cannot achieved is prioritizing one agent over another if both are idle and have the same capabilities.